# Initialising a triple nested python dictionary by reading values from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file 'objects.csv' file found here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11210856/

```
import csv
f = open('objects.csv')
X = []

for row in  csv.reader(f):
    X.append(row)

frequencyInCluster = {}
# Initialise frequency in cluster to zero for all attributes.

for i in range(15):
    for j in range(26):
        frequencyInCluster[i] = {}
        frequencyInCluster[i][j]= {}
        attr = X[i][j]
        frequencyInCluster[i][j][attr] = 0

print frequencyInCluster[0][1]
```

This gives a `KeyError: 1` . I dont understand what is wrong with this. When i write it manually without a loop , It runs perfectly. But, due to large number of rows , I need to loop it. Please help me out.

Comment: There is no `1` key inside of the `0` keys value. That is why it is giving you `KeyError 1`. print your dictionary and look at it. I see `0: {25: {'13495': 0}}`

Comment: Yes. I tried testing it manually. It worked. But this loop  doesn't work for me.

Comment: @heinst Yes, I saw that too but isnt this undesirable given i am filling the values as needed in the loop  ??

Comment: Try to move this line `frequencyInCluster[i] = {}` outside the `for j in range(26):`. Your code initials the `frequencyInCluster[i]` when the variable `j` changes every time.

Comment: @Huan-YuTseng thanks a lot. Last night submission work  leads to errors like these. Thanks a lot.